# GROUP BY non-standard MySQL to standard SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions, where-clause

My db

```
Hotel(CodHotel_PK, Name, City)
Customer(CodCustomer_PK, Name, Surname, Address, MobileNumb)
Reservation(CodCustomer_PK_FK, CodHotel_PK_FK, StartDate_PK, NumDays, PricePerDay)
```

**FOR EACH CUSTOMER** I need to find the most expensive booking that lasts less than nine days, the output must contain:

`[CodCustomer], [total price for reservation], [Hotel name], [reservation StartDate]`

This works in MySQL but not in standard SQL

```
SELECT cu.CodCustomer, MAX(rs.PricePerDay*rs.NumDays), ht.Name, rs.StartDate
FROM Customer cu
JOIN Reservation rs ON cu.CodCustomer = rs.CodCustomer
JOIN Hotel ht ON rs.CodHotel = ht.CodHotel
WHERE rs.NumDays < 9
GROUP BY cu.CodCustomer
```

The primary key for the reservation table is composite and I cannot use a single primary key

How can I run it in standard SQL? I disabled non-standard extensions with
`SET SESSION SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`

Comment: Include `ht.Name, rs.StartDate` in your `GROUP BY`

Comment: It is good that you ask this question, because if your query happens to work in MySQL, this is mere coincidence. MySQL could return any hotel and any reservation date with your query, because what MySQL silently does is this: `SELECT cu.CodCustomer, MAX(rs.PricePerDay*rs.NumDays), ANY_VALUE(ht.Name), ANY_VALUE(rs.StartDate)`.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: It is 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find the most expensive booking that last less than nine days.

I don't think aggregation is needed here. `order by` and `limit` seem sufficient:

```
select 
    cu.codcustomer, 
    rs.priceperday * rs.numdays as total_price, 
    ht.name, 
    rs.startdate
from customer    cu
join reservation rs on cu.codcustomer = rs.codcustomer
join hotel       ht on rs.codhotel    = ht.codhotel
where rs.numdays < 9
order by total_price desc limit 1
```

---

**Edit**

If you want this for each customer, then it is a bit complicated, especially in pre-8.0 versions, where window functions are not available. The base idea is that you need to filter rather than aggregate. One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    cu.codcustomer, 
    rs.priceperday * rs.numdays as total_price, 
    ht.name, 
    rs.startdate
from customer    cu
join reservation rs on cu.codcustomer = rs.codcustomer
join hotel       ht on rs.codhotel    = ht.codhotel
where rs.numdays < 9 and rs.priceperday * rs.numdays = (
    select max(rs1.priceperday * rs1.numdays) as total_price
    from reservation rs1
    where rs1.codcustomer = rs.codcustomer and rs1.numdays < 9
)
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add "for each customer" in the query request

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8 I'd use an analytic function for this. In older versions you can do with an aggregation subquery:

```
SELECT cu.CodCustomer, rs.PricePerDay * rs.NumDays, ht.Name, rs.StartDate
FROM Customer cu
JOIN Reservation rs ON cu.CodCustomer = rs.CodCustomer
JOIN Hotel ht ON rs.CodHotel = ht.CodHotel
WHERE rs.NumDays < 9
AND (rs.CodCustomer, rs.priceperday * rs.numdays) IN
(
  SELECT codcustomer, MAX(priceperday * numdays)
  FROM reservation
  WHERE numdays < 9
  GROUP BY codcustomer
);
```